# Don't know what I did wrong in class inheritance/special methods

Tags: python

I'm trying to solve a problem in my class, and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
class Company:
    def __init__(self, name=None):
        self.name = name


class Travel(Company):
    def __init__(self, name=None):
        self.name = name
        if name == None:
            name = "Generic"
        super().__init__(name)


    def __str__(self, name=None):
        self.name = name
        return "Company name:{}".format(name)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Travel('{self.name}')"

    def set_name(self, new_name):
        self.new_name = new_name
        return new_name

bever = Travel('bever')
print(bever)
bever.set_name('beverly hills')
print(bever)
```

I want it to return
Company name: bever
Company name: beverly hills

but it just returns

```
Company name: None
Company name: None
```

any help is appreciated

Comment: The `if name == None` check should be *before* you assign to `self.name`.

Comment: Why don't you just put `name = "Generic"` as the default argument?

Comment: Why does the `__str__()` method have a `name` parameter? And why does it modify the object?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change a few things:

1. Check if `name` is `None` before you assign it to `self.name`
2. `f"Travel('{self.name}')"`, you forgot to add an `f` while returning the string in `__repr__`
3. Assign `new_name` to `self.name` when you use `.set_name()`

```
class Company:
    def __init__(self, name=None):
        self.name = name


class Travel(Company):
    def __init__(self, name=None):
        if name == None:
            name = "Generic"
        self.name = name
        super().__init__(name)


    def __str__(self, name=None):
        #self.name = name
        return "Company name:{}".format(self.name)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Travel('{self.name}')"

    def set_name(self, new_name):
        self.name = new_name
        return self.name

bever = Travel('bever')
print(bever)
bever.set_name('beverly hills')
print(bever)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
class Company:
    def __init__(self, name=None):
        self.name = name


class Travel(Company):
    def __init__(self, name=None):
        if name == None:
            name = "Generic" # First set the local parameter
        self.name = name # Then the attribute
        super().__init__(name)


    def __str__(self): # str() does not expect parameters
        return f"Company name:{self.name}" # use the instance's attribute instead

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Travel('{self.name}')"

    def set_name(self, new_name):
        self.name = new_name # Update the instance's attribute
        return new_name

bever = Travel('bever')
print(bever)
bever.set_name('beverly hills')
print(bever)
```